# Scheduler job on Oracle does not run every second

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, scheduler, jobs

I have a specific scheduler job in Oracle that needs to be run every second.

I tried to create this (using a procedure):

```
begin
  sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name            => 'WBC6_PUBLIC.TESTE',
                                job_type            => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                job_action          => 'proc_insert_data',
                                start_date          => to_date('19-02-2020 09:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                                repeat_interval     => 'Freq=Secondly;Interval=1',
                                end_date            => to_date(null),
                                job_class           => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                                enabled             => true,
                                auto_drop           => false,
                                comments            => '');
end;
/
```

And this (using PLSQL_BLOCK):

```
begin
  sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name            => 'WBC6_PUBLIC.TESTE',
                                job_type            => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                                job_action          => 'insert into my_table (date) values (sysdate);',
                                start_date          => to_date('19-02-2020 09:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                                repeat_interval     => 'Freq=Secondly;Interval=1',
                                end_date            => to_date(null),
                                job_class           => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                                enabled             => true,
                                auto_drop           => false,
                                comments            => '');
end;
/
```

But the result is the same, the job runs every ~ 4 seconds.

Is there a parameter or something I can do to run every second?

Comment: That may be too small of an interval.  Why are you trying to run every second?

Comment: Because of the business rules require it. (changes item status)

Comment: I doubt you can achieve that level of performance.

Comment: Try adding    job_style        => 'LIGHTWEIGHT', to the create_job call   See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover004.htm#BGBJGHBH)

Comment: @OldProgrammer, thanks for the answer.
I tried it with LIGHTWEIGHT too and the behavior was the same.
Any other ideas?

Comment: nope.  I think you need to talk to the business folks and determine why this requirement is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something like this before and if the procedure takes or could take more than the interval, then it is impossible.  Al alternative is to run the code in a continuous loop with some kind of stop mechanism inbuilt (e.g. check a stop_table.stop_column for a "stop" condition). For example:

```
BEGIN
  LOOP 
     proc_insert_data;               /* run your insert */
     sys.DBMS_SESSION.sleep(1);      /* Pause for 1 second. */
     stop_condition := stop_condition + 1;
     EXIT WHEN stop_condition = 900; /* exit after 15 min  OR some other mechanism of  your choice */
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```